# SMS Messaging from one to many example

Tags: twilio

Does anyone know how to implement this example?
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134067-How-users-can-send-text-messages-to-each-other-over-Twilio

Answer (score 1):

The best way to implement this is using Twilio Proxy. You can find more information below.

[Introducing Twilio Proxy](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/05/introducing-twilio-proxy.html)

[Twilio Console Getting Started (when logged into the Twilio Console)](https://www.twilio.com/console/proxy/getting-started)

[Declarative APIs (Proxy, Notify, Task Router)](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/05/declarative-apis.html)

[Proxy Phone Number Management](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/understanding-phone-number-management)

[How many phone numbers do I need?](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy/phone-numbers-needed)

[Proxy: One-to-one Masked Communications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/proxy)